# How to bring a interstitial Ad to the front?

Tags: android, interstitial, inmobi

I am integrating an Inmobi interstitial AD in my android app.
The app has 2 main activitys A and B, both extends from class C, which is a superclass with a shared singleton AD variable.

When A is created, it also creates AD and loads it (only fetch).
In A, after you press a button, B starts in front of A (with startActivity(intent) ).
In B: onCreate(), it calls AD.show(), to show it if already loaded.

The problem is after B is created, AD is also created and showed, but in background. So i can not see it until dismiss B.
What i want is AD in front of B.

This same doesn't happen with Admob's interstitial, only with Inmobi.

Maybe i am not using the right approach here...
Any idea?
I am not including code because i already illustrated the problem above, but if you have any clue and need some code i will add it.

Answer (score 2):

According to what you have said, the Ad is created(only fetch) when Activity A is created that means the interstitial takes the context of Class A and this is by implementation.

Therefore calling the AD.show() from Class B would actually show the interstitial ad on top of the activity that is passed to interstitial(again by implementation) i.e on top of Activity A rather than from the activity where it is called which is in your case  Activity B.

Hope this answers your Question.

Suggestion is to create the ad from the activity where the ad is desired to be shown.

- From Inmobi

Comment: I knew that solution, that's the obvious one. But that's what i was trying to avoid, since begin loading the AD at the creation of Activity B will introduce an extra "not desirable" overhead, and maybe the AD will be shown after you see B on screen, making it annoying, or you can delay it until the AD is loaded, but can be never loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to clearly understand your query.Just to reassure it , please confirm this..
Are you concerned about the AD being shown after some time the activity B has been loaded?

- From Inmobi

Comment: Yes, as i pointed out. It's all about ease. This same behavior does not happen with other interstitial AD networks, and it's not a minor for me.